# How to control performance of image loading with picasso?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, picasso

I created a listview with custom adapter, and using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for Loading image.

The adapter is:

```
public class AdapterNews extends ArrayAdapter<StructNews> {


public AdapterNews(ArrayList<StructNews> array) {
    super(MyApplicationClass.context, R.layout.array_adapter_news, array);

}

public static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView tv1;
    ImageView img;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_tv1);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_news_list);
    }

    public void fill(ArrayAdapter<StructNews> array, final StructNews item,
            int position) {
        tv1.setText(item.text);


            if (Worker.IsFileExist(item.getUrlOffline())) {
                Picasso.with(MyApplicationClass.context).load(new File(item.getUrlOffline()))
                        .into(img);
            } else if (Worker.isNetworkConnected()) {
                Picasso.with(MyApplicationClass.context).load(item.getUrlOnline())
                        .error(R.drawable.error_no_image).into(img);
                Worker.DownloadFile(item.getUrlOnline(), item.getUrlOffline());
            }


    }

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    StructNews item = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = MyApplicationClass.inflater.inflate(R.layout.array_adapter_news,
                parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    }
    holder.fill(this, item, position);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

My news Struct:

```
public class StructNews {
public int news_number;
public String text;
public boolean IS_LOAD;

public String getUrlOffline() {
    return MyApplicationClass.PICdirFORNews + news_number + "_0.jpg";

}

public String getUrlOnline() {
    return MyApplicationClass.URL_SERVICE + "pic/news/" + news_number + "_0.jpg";

}
}
```

And i use that adapter with some data:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_news);
ArrayList<StructNews> SomeNews = new ArrayList<StructNews>();
//fill SomeNews
AdapterNews ada= new AdapterNews(SomeNews);
ada.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Problem is When activity run, the UI with listview is freezing and Lagging. when listview move this freezing Occurs again. the fill method runs more than number of items.
how to control the performance and customize the code to each imageview just one time set?

method of check file existing:

```
public static boolean IsFileExist(String FileURI) {
    File f = new File(FileURI);
    if (f.exists()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

the download method:

```
try {
                URL url = new URL(downloadPath);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.connect();



                File file = new File(filepath);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    file.delete();
                }

                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                        filepath);

                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[MyApplicationClass.DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE];
                int len = 0;
                while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);



                    }

                }

                outputStream.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and check network connection:

```
public static boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) G.context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ni == null) {
        // There are no active networks.
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you show `Worker.DownloadFile` implementation? What is this doing?

Comment: @tato.rodrigo it just download file From online source to offline destination.

Comment: Right, but how? It is hard to say what is slowing down your UI thread without seeing the concrete implementation. Possible bottlenecks are `Worker.IsFileExist(item.getUrlOffline())`, `Worker.isNetworkConnected()` and `Worker.DownloadFile`.

Comment: i added methods. how Implement fill method to picasso set image just one time for each imageview? and have any idea to instead of that codes?

Comment: for better performance i decide to use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) . and optimize the downloader and exist checker method.